# How do I test my auto-renewing subscriptions with In-app Billing API version 3 in my Android app?

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing, subscriptions

Android suggests to migrate in-app billing from API v2 to v3.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html

Android suggests that in-app billing API v3 now supports subscriptions.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Android suggests that there are still testing and real purchases.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

**If you read further down, there are requirements for test purchases:**

Test purchases are only supported for in-app products, not for in-app subscriptions.

**So how do we test in-app subscriptions in IAB v3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to test it is to actually purchase a monthly or a yearly subscription and wait until subscription expires (month/year + trial period).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of steps that are not obvious while "testing" IAB (with real purchases):

APK cannot be in Draft mode.  1) Prepare entire Store Listing with all icons, artwork, and other required fields.  I brought it up to "Ready to publish" state.  2) Then I actually published and unpublished very quickly.  3) The in-app product also has to be "Activated".  4) The APK must have Testers set using Google Groups.  5)  Also make sure that your License Key is matching your app's license key. (they are different for each app)  6) Finally, ensure that the Android Manifest version information is the same on your signed APK as it is on your Beta or Production APK that is uploaded to Google Play. (APKs can be different, but versions must be the same).

I hope this helps others avoid the pitfalls that had me struggling.

Comment: Did you manage to test a subscription purchase successfully? What about the auto renewal process?